# Make Facebook "mobile upload" photos be uploaded in high quality?

Tags: facebook

How do I make Facebook "Mobile Upload" photos upload them in high quality?

I know how to make *new* albums accept high-quality photos, but not the "Mobile Upload" album that Facebook uploads to by default.

Comment: So the thing is Facebook does compress the image either during or after the upload.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently possible. Searching help doesn't bring anything back about changing such setting. If you want to upload high quality why not create another album and call it Mobile Upload - HQ or a name more relevant?

Comment: *"Why not create another album?"* because I can make new HD albums all I want, but when I click "Share on Facebook" on my phone, it still goes in the Mobile Upload folder.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/help/www/165493740269266?q=share%20photo%20album&sid=0JDuXc2l75DguhUkj What phone are you using?

Comment: Windows Phone. And I'm not uploading to a "page", I'm uploading it to my timeline, so that link doesn't apply.

Comment: Seems you're not the only one wanting this functionality. Found this : http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4045544-select-album-while-sharing-photos-to-facebook